# CAS server authentication fails for deleted user for few minutes

Tags: java, caching, cas

Not able to login for few minutes through CAS when user is deleted and created again with exactly same values.

I have create one user with params like name, pwd, language, company.
After activating user, I am able to login.
Now I have deleted the user and recreated user with exactly same details.
And when I try to login nothing happens. I am not caching anything on my application side or in CAS server.

Only screen refreshed and page stays on login screen. No error or logs on CAS server or in my application. I have tried deleting browser cache. Tried with wrong password. Nothing works until few minutes.
after few minutes when I try login works as expected.

I am not sure if CAS server caches anything internally.
Please help me with providing some insight on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience something similar before, didn't know if related to your case but at least worth a shot:

There is a property called `cas.authn.attributeRepository.expireInMinutes` :
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#authentication-attributes

It is an caching done for **attribute**, and for my case after I set it to `cas.authn.attributeRepository.expirationTime=0` and fixed the problem

See if this also fix yours, Cheers.

Comment: Thank god someone at least replied :)   I will give it a try. Thank you